# How to load a root index file from a sub folder

Tags: php, html

I am having a subfolder that has my index file. But normally any hosting service looks for the index file after inputting the domain name. Is there a way for me to configure the root file to go to the subfolder and then look for the index file in it?

Comment: Yes, you need to change your web server settings. What web servers are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file (.htaccess) in the root directory of your site and add the bellow code to redirect you to the SubFoler.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) SubFolder/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

if you want to remove the SubFolder name from url. create other (.htaccess) file inside the SubFolder and add bellow lines.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /SubFolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this affect the performance of your website?

Comment: No, wen the url is redirected the sub folder is seated as base. The server acts normally.  WordPress uses same principle.